# Como puedo Insertar registro en posición deseada de tabla sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen dia

Quiero saber si hay alguna forma de insertar un registro en la posicion deseada en una tabla "Con mas registros"?
o la insercion en bases de datos solo funciona como una cola siempre ingresando en la ultima posicion ?

Ejemplo Tabla con Datos

dato1
dato2
dato3
dato4

luego de la insercion los datos podrian desplazarse hacia abajo?

dato1
dato2
datox
dato3
dato4

Comment: Se debe dezplazar/mover hacia abajo.

gracias por tu recomendacion

Comment: Por aportar una solución alternativa: ¿para qué quieres hacer algo así? Añadir un campo `orden` que admita flotantes y, tras cada inserción, los renumere a enteros, ¿resolvería tu problema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*TL;DR;*

**NO SE PUEDE**

Explicacion:

Las bases de datos son un programa que guarda datos priorizando lo que le convenga al momento de guardar, y ningun motor de base de datos (ansi sql) asegura que exista un orden determinado de los datos.

Los indices son punteros ordenados a los datos, pero tampoco son los datos ordenados.

Para devolver un conjunto de datos de la base de datos, ordenado, se debe usar en el select una clausula `ORDER BY`

Ningún motor de base de datos asegura que al ejecutar un select sin orden, los datos que va a traer van a venir en el mismo orden (en general, pareceria que si, pero es por temas de velocidad a la que encuentra los datos).

Ahora, si quisieras tener un campo por el cual ordenar, y agregar registros en el medio, tendrias que hacer un procedimiento almacenado, que agregara el registro en la posición (entendiendo aca que es solo un numero, no es la posicion real en la tabla) y moviera todos los numeros desde este hasta el ultimo en supongamos +1. Habria que hacer lo mismo para las eliminaciones.

Y al consultar, se consulta con un order by y la tabla viene magicamente ordenada...

Comment: De acuerdo contigo

Comment: Sácame de una duda. En SQL Server, un clustered Index **SÍ** representa datos FÍSICAMENTE ordenados. En MySql es distinto?

Comment: @Arriel todos los tipos de indices estan ordenados. Y representan fisicamente a los datos que indexan. Pero solo representan esas columnas, no las filas enteras. Y los indices, se usan cuando haces un where o un order by.. cuando no usas esas clausulas, la base de datos hace lo que quiere.

Comment: @Arriel no tengo ni idea en mysql, deberia funcionar de la misma forma. Pero igual, a lo que se pregunta aca, no serviria, porque aunque los datos se guardan ordenados, igual tendria el problema de mover la columna que considere clave para reordenarla. Creo que no es lo que preguntaba...

Answer (score 2):

Ciertamente, no se puede hacer sobre la base de Datos, aunque es indiferente, es a la hora de presentarlos en pantalla ó en un informe, cuando necesitamos manipularlos según nuestras necesidades ó criterios...

Personalmente pienso en una solución que sería:

Añadir un campo posición...

```
Dato1.....Posición
Dato2......Posición
Dato3......Posición..
```

Te fabricas un interface para editar las posiciones, para cuando quieras cambiarlas...
[Con unos cuantos UPDATE valdría... ]

Luego haces una consulta y ordenas por 'Posición' y la presentas en informe, por pantalla. etc....

Que no vá a ser fácil... lo sé...Pero se puede hacer así...

Las bases de Datos, son eso, almacenar datos segun los vas introduciendo... luego viene el como presentarlos, ordenarlos....